# Bind select element with Angular 1.5

Tags: html, angularjs, select

I don't know why when I run my page the options are well rendered but when I do a inspect element in Chrome I can see that the value of my options are not well. It gives me the value="object:8"

```
<option label="Teacher" value="object:8">Teacher</option>
```

If I replicate my code in **[fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/0mjuk6v8/)**, it works well. The value for the first option is value="1"

This "select" element is in a modal which is in a template page that is called in a ui-view

This is the html

```
<select 
       x-ng-model="filteredCategory" 
       x-ng-options="category.name for category in categories" >
    <option value="">-- Choose a category --</option>
</select>
```

This piece of code from controller

```
app.controller('CategoriesController', function ($scope, $stateParams, $uibModal, RegistrationService) {

    RegistrationService.getCategories().then(function(categories){
        $scope.categories = categories;
    });
});
```

I tested the result of my restful web service with postman chrome

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Teacher"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Student"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Coordinator"
  },
]
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article](https://www.gurustop.net/blog/2015/06/23/angularjs-1_4-select-track_by-key) that explains why angular is parsing my value as object:#.

I don't know why it doesn't work on my modal in angular but in jsfiddle works well.

Hope this help anyone else.